# How to skip empty substring while splitting a list into a sublist based on a char separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, split

I have the following list

```
list_big = ['90', '=', 'C', '44', '=']
```

my desired output is to join all strings between incidences of `'='`, like so:

```
list_smaller = ['90', 'C44']
```

I run:

```
list_smaller = [l.split(',') for l in ','.join(list_big).split('=')]
```

but I get:

```
list_smaller = [['90', ''], ['', 'C', '44', ''], ['']]
```

how can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following list-comprehension; joining with an empty string, rather than a comma, and then only putting elements in the list that aren't the empty string, using `if l`.

```
>>> [l for l in ''.join(list_big).split('=') if l]
['90', 'C44']
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you join the string with `','` if you remove that you should be fine:

```
list_smaller = [i for i in ''.join(list_big).split('=') if i]
```

Try to split up your list comprehension next time so you can see what is happening:

```
list_big = ['90', '=', 'C', '44', '=']
joined_list_big = ','.join(list_big).split('=')
joined_list_big
['90,', ',C,44,', '']
```

Here you can see this is not what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

you can use a for loop:

```
new_list = []

aux = ''
for item in list_big:
    if item != '=':
        aux += item
    else:
        new_list.append(aux)
        aux = ''

if aux:
    new_list.append(aux)

print(new_list)
```

**output:**

```
['90', 'C44']
```